# Synology API SetCameraSchedule - GET 414 Request-URI Too Large | POST 405 Not Allowed

Tags: python, api, synology

I'm trying to change camera notification schedule via Synology API.

GET request returns 414 Request-URI Too Large
POST request returns 405 Not Allowed

It seems to be impossible to do this with get request. Please help me to fix POST request!

Here are docs of this method:
Page 241 SetCameraSchedule
https://usdl.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Surveillance_Station_Web_API_v2.6.pdf

GET func returns: Request-URI Too Large

```
def syn_cam_notification_shedule_set(cam_id, event_type, state):
cam_id = str(cam_id)
event_type = str(event_type)
state = str(state)
url = 'https://'+server+'/webapi/entry.cgi?version="1"&schedule=[{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"}]&eventType='+event_type+'&cameraId='+cam_id+'&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Notification.Schedule"&method="SetCameraSchedule"'
print(url)
r = s.get(url, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

POST func returns: 405 Not Allowed

```
def syn_cam_notification_shedule_set(cam_id, event_type, state):
cam_id = cam_id
event_type = event_type
state = str(state)
url = 'https://'+server+'/webapi/entry.cgi'

data = {
    '_sid': sid,
    'version': '1',
    'schedule': '[{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"},{"schedule":"'+state+'"}]',
    'eventType': event_type,
    'cameraId': cam_id,
    'api': 'SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Notification.Schedule',
    'method': 'SetCameraSchedule'
}
r = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

Here is my other code:

```
s = requests.Session()

def syn_login():
    url = 'https://'+server+"/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=Login&version=6&account="+login+"&passwd="+password+"&session=SurveillanceStation"
    r = s.get(url, verify=False)
    r_json = json.loads(r.text)
    if r_json['success']:
        print(r_json['data']['sid'])
        return r_json['data']['sid']

sid = syn_login()
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by modifying my Synology Nginx configuration (access by SSH)

I create a new file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/http.size.conf`

And add this content :

```
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
```

Then restart your nginx service with `sudo synoservicectl --restart nginx`

I am developping a library in Python to interact with Surveillance Station API if your are interested : [here](https://github.com/k20human/surveillancestation)

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Does your library requires modification of nginx configuration?

Comment: The only modification you need is for the schedule set due to URI too large